# .Net Get property name

Tags: .net

I would like to get the name of a property, for example:

```
Dim _foo As String

Public Property Foo as String
Get
   Return _foo
End Get
Private Set(ByVal value as String)
   _foo = value
End Set

Sub Main()
  Console.Write(Foo.Name)'Outputs "Foo"
End Sub
```

Any ideas how?

Comment: You want the string `"Name"`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do you mean a property, or do you mean a field?

There are clever lambda techniques for getting the names of properties - here's a C# example:

```
String GetPropertyName<TValue>(Expression<Func<TValue>> propertyId)
{
   return ((MemberExpression)propertyId.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
GetPropertyName(() => MyProperty)
```

and it will return "MyProperty"

Not sure if that's what you're after or not.

Comment: My mistake my mind was somewhere else when I wrote the example. Changed it now

Comment: the call example should be:
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
GetPropertyName(() => obj.MyProperty)

Comment: Do you know .NET 2.0 way of doing this?

Comment: In 2.0, you need to use reflection rather than Expressions.

Comment: is there any way to do this for a property on a other type then the current instance? without having a instance of it?

Answer (score 13):

If you are using C# 6.0 (not released when this question was asked) you can use the following:

```
nameof(PropertyName)
```

This is evaluated at compile time and is converted to a string, the nice thing about using `nameof()` is that you don't have to manually change a string when you refactor.
(`nameof` works on more than Properties, `CallerMemberName` is more restrictive)

If you are still stuck in pre c# 6.0 then you can use `CallerMemberNameAttribute` (it requires .net 4.5)

```
private static string Get([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string name = "")
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    return name;
}
```

Comment: I don't why this was not well appreciated, but this method is really neat. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
public static PropertyInfo GetPropInfo<T>(this T @object
    , Expression<Action<T>> propSelector)
{
    MemberExpression exp= propSelector.Body as MemberExpression;
    return exp.Member as PropertyInfo;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
string str = ....
string propertyName = str.GetPropInfo(a => a.Length).Name;
```

Note that the above method is an extension and should be written in a static class and used by including the namespace

Comment: Or in the case of the OP, in VB it's an extension method that should be in a Module (not static class) and decorated with the Extension attribute rather than the this keyword.

Answer (score 0):

via reflection. Use GetType() method of the type, then look into GetProperties() method and PropertyInfo class. (if you'd like to retrieve the string "propertyName" (for a *field* called propertyName - use xxx.GetType().GetFields()[0].Name if it's first field in the class.

Comment: This works only if you know the index of the property in the class, which is not really realiable as the class can change or may be partial.