# column mapping to property is it possible on lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, .net

I parse table with prices, I created class IConfig which configurates column mappings as it differs from price files to another, and need to map column to an object property

```
CsvParserConfig config = new CsvParserConfig();
config.MapColumn("col1", x => x.Sku);
```

is it possible on lambda expressions?

Comment: Please share more of your code.

Comment: It depends on the signature of MapColumn

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - you need to map a column name to a certain property. You can do so using reflection.

There are a plenty of examples around (first google hit: [.Net Get property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341666/net-get-property-name)) that allow you to get the name of a property from a lambda function. In lieu of returning the string, you could configure it to return an instance of `PropertyInfo` so you can extract the value from the property that is determined at runtime.