# How to get a string representation of a property name of a Model in MVC3?

Tags: string, asp.net-mvc-3, class, variables, model

I have the following model:

```
Public Class MyModel

    Public Property MyModelId As Integer
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property AnotherProperty As String

End Class
```

Is there a method to get a property name of the Model as a string representation like the following code?

```
Dim propertyName as String = GetPropertyNameAsStringMethod(MyModel.Description)
```

So the propertyName variable has "Description" as value.

Comment: there are no such method that do as you want. you get the properties name using reflection. `    string prop = "name";
    PropertyInfo pi = myObject.GetType().GetProperty(prop);`

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341666/net-get-property-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Darin Dimitrov' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4657360/770710) on this SO thread - [Reflection - get property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657311/reflection-get-property-name).

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var result = Get<Foo, string>(x => x.Bar);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static string Get<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
    {
        var me = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (me != null)
        {
            return me.Member.Name;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this help..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a helper extension method you can use for any property:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static string PropertyName<T>(this T owner, 
        Expression<Func<T, object>> expression) where T : class
    {
        if (owner == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("owner");
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }

}
```

However, this will only work on instances of a class. You can write a similar extension method that will operate directly on the type instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it using reflection.

There are already loads of posts on stack overflow like this:

[How to get current property name via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206023/how-to-get-current-property-name-via-reflection)

[Reflection - get property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657311/reflection-get-property-name)

[Get string name of property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661824/get-string-name-of-property-using-reflection)

[Reflection - get property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657311/reflection-get-property-name)

I believe that the answer will be along the lines of:

```
 string prop = "name"; 
 PropertyInfo pi = myObject.GetType().GetProperty(prop);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension method and then use it where needed.

```
Private Shared Function GetPropertyName(Of T)(exp As Expression(Of Func(Of T))) As String
    Return (DirectCast(exp.Body, MemberExpression).Member).Name
End Function
```

have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657311/reflection-get-property-name) post as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue editing a bit @NiranjanKala's source example,

converting the code in vb.Net like this

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function GetPropertyName(Of T, TResult)(expression As Expression(Of Func(Of T, TResult))) As String
    Dim [me] = TryCast(expression.Body, MemberExpression)
    If [me] IsNot Nothing Then
        Return [me].Member.Name
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Then I am able to call the extension like this

```
Dim propertyName as String = GetPropertyName(Of MyModel, String)(Function(x) x.Description)
```

Then propertyName variable has "Description" as string value.

Comment: beware that this approach is not the fastest though.